# can you compare an int to a bus in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I know this is probably trivial, but this is the umpteenth time I've googled it so I'd like to get a definitive answer.

I have the following code in a testbench, so it need not be synthesizable. Will this comparison work as expected?

```
logic [4:0] bus;

task mytask;
    input int i;
    begin
        if(i == bus)
            $write("Match");
    end
endtask
```

Comment: Did you try it? See http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Vc3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dwikle has pointed out, the answer is yes. But in the spirit of teaching a man to fish, you might like to know why...

In System-Verilog there are 2-state types and 4-state types. 2-states can only take the values 0 and 1; 4-state types can take the values 0, 1, X and Z. `logic` is a 4-state type; `bit` is a 2-state type.

You can make "buses" out of either:

```
logic [7:0] my_4_state_8_bit_bus;
bit   [7:0] my_2_state_8_bit_bus;
```

These can also be signed or unsigned:

```
logic signed [7:0] my_4_state_signed_8_bit_bus;
bit unsigned [7:0] my_2_state_unsigned_8_bit_bus;
```

Type `int` is merely a predefined, 32-bit, signed, 2-state bus:

```
int               this_is_the_same;
bit signed [31:0] as_this;
```

You can assign a 4-state type to a 2-state type. If you assign a 4-state type to a 2-state type, X's and Z's are converted to 0's.

You can compare a 4-state type with a 2-state type. If any bit of the 4-state type is X or Z then the result of the comparison will be 1'bX.

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Rdu